# Javascript regex all characters up till word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a strings like this:

```
blah-ha-ID:
asdf
```

I want to match all characters up till the final -ID:

So my initial regex was:

```
^[^-]+
```

This worked until words starting have hypnes in them. So in the example above, in `blah-ha-ID:` it would select up till `blah` when it should have got `blah-ha`.

So I was trying something like this, i want to repeat all characters that are not `-ID`

```
^[^-ID]+
```

But of course that wont work. I can't use capturing, and I need it to exclude the final `-ID`

More then workarounds I was hoping to learn how to do this, i recall there was a way to repeat up till a "word" in these character classes.

Comment: You don't need Regexp, use String's `lastIndexOf` instead

Comment: Thanks @hindmost but I need to use this in a simple replace. Without going capturing and using function replace.

Comment: You can still use `lastIndexOf` to replace. `substr`/`substring` will help.

Comment: @hindmost i think problem with lastIndexOf is what if doesnt have the `-ID` in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(.+?)(?=-ID|$)/
```

This will match 1 or more characters from start to literal `-ID` or line end.  `-ID` is in a positive lookahead so it won't be matched.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tP8lA3/1)

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, but i need it to not select the -ID at the end :( And I cant use capuring :(

Comment: Thanks for your edit it works for my case but is it possible to do my gorup thing? I was hoping to learn it if possible.

Comment: There was some trick like `[^-[^I[^D]]]]` but Ill accept your solution as soon as stack allows me.

Comment: That kind of trick becomes very clumsy for longer text so I would suggest that only when lookahead isn't available.

Comment: Ah the problem with this, is that if it doesnt have `-ID` at the end it comes with no match :(

Comment: So if a line only has `asdf` then you want to match `asdf` also ?

Comment: Indeed, as he wrote in the OP. New [test case](https://regex101.com/r/bY4iW1/6) which does fail presently.

Comment: Then OP can use: `/^(.+?)(?=-ID|$)/`

Comment: @anubhava has met all of the cases present. I added a degenerate case which was not in the OP, which does [fail](https://regex101.com/r/bY4iW1/10) for this regex.

Answer (score 1):

This works for all [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/bY4iW1/9)

```
^.*(?=-ID)|.*[^-ID:]
```

where I have added the degenerate case of `-ID:` on a line by itself.

Comment: Thank you this is so interesting